# How take out diffence file of git of this commit compared to Last time commit

Tags: git

I know that `git diff` will show the differences of last commit; when I am done with developing a requirement, actually I don't want to commit all of the project's files to one package to replace it, I just want to take out those files I modified, and keep the directory structure.

example below

```
src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/Applicaiton.java                     |  2 +-
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/center/Center.java                   | 30 +++++++++++++++++++++---------
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/center/DefaultCenter.java            |  1 +
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/center/MaxRepostry.java              | 44 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/center/PieceCenter.java              | 65 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/center/Repostry.java                 | 64 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++------------------------------
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/conf/Config.java                     | 13 +++++--------
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/delegate/DelegateRunner.java         | 21 ++++++++++++++++++---
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/extract/AbstractExTractCallback.java |  7 +++++++
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/extract/DefaultExtractCallback.java  |  6 ++----
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/extract/FalselyExtractCallback.java  |  4 +---
 src/main/java/com/sc/eefile/extract/PieceExtractCallback.java    | 48 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 12 files changed, 247 insertions(+), 58 deletions(-)
```

I want to take out those files to a package and keep the directory structure.

Notice the image show files is source code, paket need files is that after compile.

Comment: So, you want to pack up the compiled object files for all the source files that changed?

Comment: @jthill yeah,as you said , has some convenient method? and best , can keep directory structure

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I tried my best to improve your English. Remember: if you could have somebody proof-read your question before posting, ask them to do so. It will help with context and meaning lost in traslation.

Comment: @DaemonPainter thanks I will do this after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d @~ \
| sed 's,\.java$,.o' | tar Tcf - newstuff.tar
```

Comment: Roughly understand ，thank you vary much , I will try write a shell script to improve the command